# DOM doesn't update when value in a 2D array changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tic-tac-toe

I created this [titactoe](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-14zrbf?file=/src/components/TicTacToe.vue) game  but when I click on the cells, DOM doesn't update the cell with the correct value (either `X` or `O`). I believe it is due to the board array being two dimensional. I tried this line of code to update cell values but it still doesn't work:

```
{{ cell === 'X' ? 'close' : cell === 'O' ? 'circle' : '' }}
```

Anyone knows how to fix it so when clicking on a cell it shows the corresponding value either `X` or `O` from `board` array?

Update: **This is my entire code**

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TicTacToe />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TicTacToe from "./components/TicTacToe.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { TicTacToe },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

TicTacToe.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="tic-tac-toe">
    <div class="row" v-for="(row, x) in board" :key="x">
      <div
        class="cell"
        v-for="(cell, y) in row"
        :key="y"
        @click="cellClicked(x, y)"
      >
        {{ cell }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      player: "X",
      winner: null,
      board: [
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""],
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    winningCondition(board) {
      const condition = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [2, 5, 8],
      ];
      for (let i = 0; i < condition.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = condition[i];
        if (board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c]) {
          return (this.winner = board[a]);
        }
      }
      return (this.winner = null);
    },
    cellClicked(x, y) {
      if (this.winner) return;
      if (this.board[x][y]) return;
      this.board[x][y] = this.player;
      this.player = this.player === "X" ? "O" : "X";
      this.winningCondition(this.board.flat());
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.cell {
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tic-tac-toe {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could create a copy of your 2D array, modify it, then reassign the original one, like instead of `this.board[x][y] = this.player;` you do `const temp = this.board.slice(); temp[x][y] = this.player; this.board = temp;`

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, preferably as a [MCVE]. What you have provided has no indication on how you are attempting to update the DOM

Comment: @JonP bro literally just click on the link and it takes you to a  working sandbox !

Comment: Or just include relevant code in the question itself. That is generally what is expected on StackOverflow. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by including code **here**. Offsite links can go down, collaborative sites are sometimes blocked by corporate firewalls.

Comment: alternative to @code's suggestion is just `this.board[x].splice(y, 1, this.player);`

Comment: @JonP updated the question with my code

Comment: @code
I think the issue is DOM doesn't detect changes in a 2d nest array. How does your solution address this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by DOM. If you mean Vue, it uses built-in JavaScript object change sensors, and if you alter something inside an array it won't fire, so we create a new array and alter the original object. Have you tried my proposed solution?